# Datatable select with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, select, datatable

I have a datatable with 4 columns A, B, C and D such that a particular combination of values for column A, B and C is unique in the datatable.

**Objective:** To find the value of column D, for a given combination of values for column A, B and C.

I guess looping over the set of data rows should do it. Is there a way to use Datatable.Select() to accomplish this? To be more specific - can I have multiple conditions in the select filter i.e. a logical AND operator connecting conditions for each of the columns A, B and C.

Comment: So column D is a computed column, based on A, B, and C?

Comment: have you considered emiting this as a query, and letting the database do what it's there for?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Yes, the `DataTable.Select` method supports boolean operators in the same way that you would use them in a "real" SQL statement:

```
DataRow[] results = table.Select("A = 'foo' AND B = 'bar' AND C = 'baz'");
```

See [DataColumn.Expression in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) for the syntax supported by DataTable's `Select` method.

Answer (score 46):

Do you have to use `DataTable.Select()`?  I prefer to write a linq query for this kind of thing.

```
var dValue=  from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
             where row.Field<int>("A") == 1 
                   && row.Field<int>("B") == 2 
                   && row.Field<int>("C") == 3
             select row.Field<string>("D");
```

Comment: +1 from me, too. It's better visible as programming language than as SQL command. Sincerely, I don't know which of them is faster, but I like this one more.

Comment: Linq is faster and recommended in cases like these

Answer (score 7):

I found that having too many and's would return incorrect results (for .NET 1.1 anyway)

```
DataRow[] results = table.Select("A = 'foo' AND B = 'bar' AND C = 'baz' and D ='fred' and E = 'marg'");
```

In my case A was the 12th field in a table and the select was effectively ignoring it.

However if I did

```
DataRow[] results = table.Select("A = 'foo' AND (B = 'bar' AND C = 'baz' and D ='fred' and E = 'marg')");
```

The filter worked correctly!

Comment: That has to be some bug of sorts. There is no logically difference between your two examples.

Answer (score 6):

Try this,
I think ,this is one of the simple solutions.

```
int rowIndex = table.Rows.IndexOf(table.Select("A = 'foo' AND B = 'bar' AND C = 'baz'")[0]);
string strD= Convert.ToString(table.Rows[rowIndex]["D"]);
```

Make sure,combination of values for column A, B and C is unique in the datatable.

Comment: Your solution `int rowIndex = ... [0]` can only return the first row matched, even though the request is to return a "unique" value, there might be multiple values which are then just ignored. Why not `int[] rowIndex = ...` and return any result. The focus being that if the so called unique combination is not unique and there is a data fault then it can be remedied.

Answer (score 2):

```
    protected void FindCsv()
    {
        string strToFind = "2";

        importFolder = @"C:\Documents and Settings\gmendez\Desktop\";

        fileName = "CSVFile.csv";

        connectionString= @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq="+importFolder+";Extended Properties=Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited";
        conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

        System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter  da = new OdbcDataAdapter("select * from [" + fileName + "]", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = "id";

        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("id=" + strToFind);

        Response.Write(dr[0][0].ToString() + dr[0][1].ToString() + dr[0][2].ToString() + dr[0][3].ToString() + dr[0][4].ToString() + dr[0][5].ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim dr As DataRow()


dr = dt.Select("A="& a & "and B="& b & "and C=" & c,"A",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
```

Where A,B,C are the column names
where second parameter is for sort expression

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to run into lots of annoying errors (datediff and such can't be evaluated in `DataTable.Select` among other things and even if you do as suggested use `DataTable.AsEnumerable` you will have trouble evaluating DateTime fields) do the following:

1) Model Your Data (create a class with DataTable columns)

Example

```
public class Person
{
public string PersonId { get; set; }
public DateTime DateBorn { get; set; }
}
```

2) Add this helper class to your code

```
public static class Extensions
{
/// <summary>
/// Converts datatable to list<T> dynamically
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Class name</typeparam>
/// <param name="dataTable">data table to convert</param>
/// <returns>List<T></returns>
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable dataTable) where T : new()
{
    var dataList = new List<T>();

    //Define what attributes to be read from the class
    const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

    //Read Attribute Names and Types
    var objFieldNames = typeof(T).GetProperties(flags).Cast<PropertyInfo>().
        Select(item => new
        {
            Name = item.Name,
            Type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(item.PropertyType) ?? item.PropertyType
        }).ToList();

    //Read Datatable column names and types
    var dtlFieldNames = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
        Select(item => new {
            Name = item.ColumnName,
            Type = item.DataType
        }).ToList();

    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList())
    {
        var classObj = new T();

        foreach (var dtField in dtlFieldNames)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfos = classObj.GetType().GetProperty(dtField.Name);

            var field = objFieldNames.Find(x => x.Name == dtField.Name);

            if (field != null)
            {

                if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    propertyInfos.SetValue
                    (classObj, ConvertToDateTime(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                }
                else if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                {
                    propertyInfos.SetValue
                    (classObj, ConvertToInt(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                }
                else if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(long))
                {
                    propertyInfos.SetValue
                    (classObj, ConvertToLong(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                }
                else if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(decimal))
                {
                    propertyInfos.SetValue
                    (classObj, ConvertToDecimal(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                }
                else if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(String))
                {
                    if (dataRow[dtField.Name].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        propertyInfos.SetValue
                        (classObj, ConvertToDateString(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        propertyInfos.SetValue
                        (classObj, ConvertToString(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dataList.Add(classObj);
    }
    return dataList;
}

private static string ConvertToDateString(object date)
{
    if (date == null)
        return string.Empty;

    return HelperFunctions.ConvertDate(Convert.ToDateTime(date));
}

private static string ConvertToString(object value)
{
    return Convert.ToString(HelperFunctions.ReturnEmptyIfNull(value));
}

private static int ConvertToInt(object value)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(HelperFunctions.ReturnZeroIfNull(value));
}

private static long ConvertToLong(object value)
{
    return Convert.ToInt64(HelperFunctions.ReturnZeroIfNull(value));
}

private static decimal ConvertToDecimal(object value)
{
    return Convert.ToDecimal(HelperFunctions.ReturnZeroIfNull(value));
}

private static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(object date)
{
    return Convert.ToDateTime(HelperFunctions.ReturnDateTimeMinIfNull(date));
}

}
public static class HelperFunctions
{

public static object ReturnEmptyIfNull(this object value)
{
    if (value == DBNull.Value)
        return string.Empty;
    if (value == null)
        return string.Empty;
    return value;
}
public static object ReturnZeroIfNull(this object value)
{
    if (value == DBNull.Value)
        return 0;
    if (value == null)
        return 0;
    return value;
}
public static object ReturnDateTimeMinIfNull(this object value)
{
    if (value == DBNull.Value)
        return DateTime.MinValue;
    if (value == null)
        return DateTime.MinValue;
    return value;
}
/// <summary>
/// Convert DateTime to string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="datetTime"></param>
/// <param name="excludeHoursAndMinutes">if true it will execlude time from datetime string. Default is false</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ConvertDate(this DateTime datetTime, bool excludeHoursAndMinutes = false)
{
    if (datetTime != DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        if (excludeHoursAndMinutes)
            return datetTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return datetTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

3) Easily convert your `DataTable` (dt) to a List of objects with following code:

```
List<Person> persons = Extensions.ToList<Person>(dt);
```

4) have fun using Linq without the annoying `row.Field<type>` bit you have to use when using `AsEnumerable`

Example

```
var personsBornOn1980 = persons.Where(x=>x.DateBorn.Year == 1980);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //  Create Your YourDataTableSample.
        //  And Add New columns and Some rows.
        DataTable YourDataTableSample = new DataTable("SampleDT");
        YourDataTableSample.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
        YourDataTableSample.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MyDate", typeof(DateTime)));
        YourDataTableSample.Rows.Add(100, new DateTime(2021, 1, 1));
        YourDataTableSample.Rows.Add(200, new DateTime(2022, 2, 1));
        YourDataTableSample.Rows.Add(300, new DateTime(2023, 3, 1));
        
        // Select by MyDate.
        DataRow[] TheResult = YourDataTableSample.Select("MyDate > #6/1/2021#");
        
        // Display The Result.
        foreach (DataRow TheRow in TheResult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TheRow["ID"]);
        }
    }
}
```