# Access Database select more than one row in c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, select

I have been following this site for basic Access database implementation in C#

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p12.html

I want to search more than one row. This code works for one row.

```
string searchFor = txtFurniture.Text;
returnedRows = ds1.Tables["Furniture"].Select("Finish='" + searchFor + "'");
```

How do I add in additional rows to check? I have tried something like

```
returnedRows = ds1.Tables["Furniture"].Select("Finish='" + "Style='" + searchFor + "'");
```

but this fails.

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1):

you need to add and condition

```
returnedRows = ds1.Tables["Furniture"].Select("Finish='" + searchFor +
                                           "' and Style='" + searchFor + "'");
```

In addition you can check this answer might help you to understand easily : [Datatable select with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990946/datatable-select-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 1):

You mean an additional field to check.

Make a condition that looks like this:

```
Finish='something' and Style='something'
```

using:

```
returnedRows = ds1.Tables["Furniture"].Select("Finish='" + searchFor + "' and Style='" + searchFor + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

As referenced in the [documentation for the DataTable.Select method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/det4aw50.aspx), the [documentation for the DataColumn.Expression property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) describes the syntax to be used with the `filterExpression` parameter.  In your case, use `And` to create a compound expression with your two conditions:

```
returnedRows = ds1.Tables["Furniture"].Select("Finish='" + searchFor + "' And Style='" + searchFor2 + "'");
```

...or more readably...

```
string filterExpression = string.Format("Finish='{0}' And Style='{1}'", searchFor, searchFor2);
DataRow[] returnedRows = ds1.Tables["Furniture"].Select(filterExpression);
```