# Datatable select with multiple conditions SQL Query issue

Tags: datatable, vb.net-2010

From [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990946/datatable-select-with-multiple-conditions), its answer is almost my answer. But I am facing some sql query issue, I have the following statement in VB

```
Dim results As DataRow() = table.Select("A = 'foo' AND B = 'bar' AND C = 'baz'")
```

**I want to place** `foo, bar and baz` **in variables and use that variables in above statements.**

```
Dim Varfoo As String = "foo"
Dim Varbar As String = "bar"
Dim Varbaz As String = "baz"
```

I managed to get one variable in statement as

```
 Dim results As DataRow() = table.Select("A = " + Varfoo)
```

**But how to insert multiple sort expressions with variables?**

**Edit:** I got it solved with the answer of **vikas** as following;

```
Dim results As DataRow() = table.Select("A = '" & Varfoo & "' And B = '" & Varbar & "' And C = '" & Varbaz & "'")
```

Comment: You can refer to this link: have more explanation: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Dim results As DataRow() = table.Select("A = '" & Varfoo & "'")
```

**Edited**

For OR operation

```
Dim results As DataRow() = table.Select("A = '" & Varfoo & "' OR B = '" & Varbar & "' OR C = '" & Varbaz & "'")
```

For AND operation

```
Dim results As DataRow() = table.Select("A = '" & Varfoo & "' AND B = '" & Varbar & "' AND C = '" & Varbaz & "'")
```

Comment: @AbdulAziz did u try my logic

Comment: This also for the single sort expression as i mention Dim results As DataRow() = table.Select("A = " + Varfoo) which is working fine. But I want for multiple sort expressions using 'AND'.

Comment: Hey I got it working with your answer. Thanks a lot Man. Please see my edited question for how i solved it.