# check if a value exists in DataRow array

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application i am filtering a datatable using a filter expression and am getting a DataRow which matches the condition.Now i want to check if the value of particular column exists in any row of  DataRow array.

**Code**:

```
string FilterCond1 = "id=" + getId;
DataRow[] myrow = DataTable.Select(FilterCond1);
if (myrow.Length > 0)
{
//check for size=28 in DataRow[]
}
else
{
}
```

I have column **size** in the datatable `DataTable` and i want to check if any row of the DataRow array has a value **28** in the column `size`.How can i go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
string FilterCond1 = "id=" + getId;
DataRow[] myrow = DataTable.Select(FilterCond1);
if (myrow.Length > 0)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < myrow.Length; i ++)
  {
    if(myrow[i]["size"].ToString() == "28")
    {
      // YOUR CODE HERE 
    }
  }
}
else
{
}
```

**EDIT**

Just add the condition to your filter.

```
string FilterCond1 = "id=" + getId + " AND size=28";
```

Then you don't need the `if(myrow[i]["size"].ToString() == "28")` as you know the rows in the array are the one you want.

Comment: How to pass a string instead of 28 in FilterCond1

Comment: How do you mean? Do you want the size to be a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use column collection to access particular column value within row.

```
if(myrow[rowIndex]["ColoumnName"].ToString() == "somevalue")
```

*Where row index could from zero to length-1*

**Edit** based on comments, you can put multiple condition on column in select, check it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990946/datatable-select-with-multiple-conditions), and may not need to iterate.

```
string FilterCond1 = "id=" + getId + " AND size = " + 28;
DataRow[] myrow = dt.Select(FilterCond1);
```

To iterate through rows collection

```
for(int i=0; i < myrow.Length; i++)
{
   if(myrow[i]["size"].ToString() == "28")
   {
        //your code
   }
}
```

Comment: Its giving me an error cannot implicitly convert type string to int.

Comment: You would be comparing string with int, change condition to if(int.Parse(myrow["ColoumnName"].ToString()) == 123)

Comment: Sorry I thought myrow is row object but it row object array, you need to use indexer, if(myrow[0]["ColoumnName"].ToString() == "somevalue") also check my updated answer

Comment: I know we should use row indexer.But i want check in all rows whether the value exists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27939/discussion-between-adil-and-smith269)

Answer (score 0):

First you should aiterate through all rows using foreach then use the below code..

```
if(myrow[row]["size"] == 28)
```

### or

```
int ColIndex = 3; // replace 3 with ur co. index 
if(myrow[row][ColIndex] == 28)
```