# Can I add an array to a row of a DataTable (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, visual-studio, datatable

As of now, I'm trying to add my `subject1weightingsarray` to a row of my Datatable. The array isn't of a DataRow type so I'm not sure if I can just add a row or if I have to do something else to add the array into the row?

```
TextBox[] subject1weightingsarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname1task1weighting, subjectname1task2weighting, subjectname1task3weighting, subjectname1task4weighting, subjectname1task5weighting, subjectname1task6weighting };
TextBox[] subject2weightingsarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname2task1weighting, subjectname2task2weighting, subjectname2task3weighting, subjectname2task4weighting, subjectname2task5weighting, subjectname2task6weighting };
TextBox[] subject3weightingsarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname3task1weighting, subjectname3task2weighting, subjectname3task3weighting, subjectname3task4weighting, subjectname3task5weighting, subjectname3task6weighting };
TextBox[] subject4weightingsarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname4task1weighting, subjectname4task2weighting, subjectname4task3weighting, subjectname4task4weighting, subjectname4task5weighting, subjectname4task6weighting };
TextBox[] subject5weightingsarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname5task1weighting, subjectname5task2weighting, subjectname5task3weighting, subjectname5task4weighting, subjectname5task5weighting, subjectname5task6weighting };
TextBox[] subject6weightingsarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname6task1weighting, subjectname6task2weighting, subjectname6task3weighting, subjectname6task4weighting, subjectname6task5weighting, subjectname6task6weighting };

TextBox[] subject1marksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname1task1weighting, subjectname1task2weighting, subjectname1task3weighting, subjectname1task4weighting, subjectname1task5weighting, subjectname1task6weighting };
TextBox[] subject2marksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname2task1weighting, subjectname2task2weighting, subjectname2task3weighting, subjectname2task4weighting, subjectname2task5weighting, subjectname2task6weighting };
TextBox[] subject3marksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname3task1weighting, subjectname3task2weighting, subjectname3task3weighting, subjectname3task4weighting, subjectname3task5weighting, subjectname3task6weighting };
TextBox[] subject4marksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname4task1weighting, subjectname4task2weighting, subjectname4task3weighting, subjectname4task4weighting, subjectname4task5weighting, subjectname4task6weighting };
TextBox[] subject5marksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname5task1weighting, subjectname5task2weighting, subjectname5task3weighting, subjectname5task4weighting, subjectname5task5weighting, subjectname5task6weighting };
TextBox[] subject6marksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname6task1weighting, subjectname6task2weighting, subjectname6task3weighting, subjectname6task4weighting, subjectname6task5weighting, subjectname6task6weighting };

DataTable MarksWeightingRecordDataTable = new DataTable();
MarksWeightingRecordDataTable.Clear();
foreach (string subjectname in datatablesubjectnamearray)
{
    MarksWeightingRecordDataTable.Columns.Add(subjectname);
}

foreach (DataColumn datatablesubjectnames in MarksWeightingRecordDataTable.Columns)
{

    DataRow row = MarksWeightingRecordDataTable.NewRow();

    MarksWeightingRecordDataTable.Rows.Add(subject1weightingsarray); /* work just with array?*/

}
```

Comment: You can make a `DataRow` array as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922826/check-if-a-value-exists-in-datarow-array)

Comment: I think you have to create a DataRow as you have done, then loop through your weightings array and add a cell to the datarow (in the correct order) for each item in the array. Hopefully Intellisense is already telling you that your array is of the wrong type to add it as you are trying to

Comment: I never saw controls (`Windows.Forms.TextBox` in your case) added to a datatable. what are you trying to achieve? Most likely you'll rather want to add the value of the `Text` property of those textboxes instead, or use an editable grid if the goal is to write a tabular editor.