# Adding proper Select arguments for VB

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, select

I am using this line:

```
For Each dtrow In FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.Select("Floor ='3'")
```

to select all items from `Floor = 3`
How can I add another argument the states..

```
.Select(Building = Mall and Floor = 3)
```

where it will find all data that has `Mall` as building, then get all from the third floor.
I tried something like : `.Select("Floor ='3' And Building ="'"Mall"'"")` - but it seems I am doing it wrong. I am not really good in sql.
Also, I am planning on using variables for `Mall` and `3`.. If you would be so kind, make it that way thanks :)

**UPDATE:** I tried valverij answer and it comes down to this: (*though `Floor=3` code is still working*)
[image]

Comment: by *roper* did you mean *proper* in the title?

Comment: sorry about that :) that wasn't my title at first, maybe I've accidentally deleted P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your multiple-condition `Select` has way too many quotes in it. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990946/datatable-select-with-multiple-conditions), you should just be able to do something like this:

```
.Select("Floor ='3' AND Building ='Mall'")
```

I'm not sure if the capitalization matters there, but you'd might as well make the `AND` all caps while you're at it.

You can also do this with LINQ using [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
For Each dtrow In FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(dr) dr("Floor") = "3" AndAlso dr("Building") = "Mal
```

**UPDATE:** Based on the update to your question, it looks like `nBtn.Name` is expecting one type, and your statement is implicitly trying to set it to something else. If you set `Option Strict On` at the top of your file, VB will force you to cast explicitly where necessary when setting/using your objects. If you don't want to do that, that's fine, but it might come down to doing something like this:

```
nBtn.Name = dtrow("ButtonText").ToString & dtrow("ID").ToString
```

or this:

```
nBtn.Name = String.Format("{0}{1}", dtrow("ButtonText").ToString, dtrow("ID").ToString)
```

Also, check to make sure that `dtrow("ButtonText")` and `dtrow("ID")` actually contain a value (i.e., that they aren't `DBNull.Value`) If *that's* the problem, then you can use temporary variables along with `If` statements to set them accordingly:

```
Dim buttonText As String = String.Empty
Dim id As String = String.Empty

If dtrow("ButtonText") IsNot DBNull.Value Then
    nBtn.Name &= dtrow("ButtonText").ToString
End If

If dtrow("ID") IsNot DBNull.Value Then
    nBtn.Name &= dtrow("ID").ToString
End If
```

Note, though, the `ToString` will make *sure* that VB grabs the `String` representation of the value in your `DataRow`. Otherwise, I think it just tries to use the type based on what was added when the `DataRow` was created.

Comment: does making either of them in the front make a difference?

Comment: I don't think so, but the syntax for `DataTable.Select` might be slightly different than regular SQL. Here's an article outlining the use of the row filter syntax. It's in C#, but the syntax for the `Select` should be the same: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/ Keep in mind that `NULL` records might throw it off.

Comment: thanks for the link, can you check my updated question?

Comment: @AdorableVB, it looks like there's an implicit typing issue between `nBtn.Name` and the value in your `DataRow`. I've updated my answer to include that.

Comment: got it, although, I still get the same error, I am pretty sure that there is something wrong with the `for each` line. Is there any other way that gives the same output that I want?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I think I have my answer now. Just use `AND` :)

Comment: Not a problem. I figured I'd throw the LINQ in there as an extra example, sorry if it caused some confusion.

Comment: And I just realized the LINQ example should have been a Where, not a Select.